# Ordinal not found

Tags: mfc, ordinal

can anyone give me any advice on what to do about this error ?!
i made a simple mfc app which works on windows7 but on winXP it throws the bellow error :

"The ordinal 7118 could not be located in the dynamic link lybrary mfc90.dll"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is really obvious, you are using an older MFC dll that is not present on Windows XP hence the ordinal 7118 could not be located...Perhaps copy the MFC90.DLL to that Windows XP installation into the `C:\Windows\System32`, that should resolve the error. If not, then it could be that MFC90.DLL is relying on an API found in Windows 7 that is not present in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all locations which may conflict by running the command:

```
where mfc90*
```

Then remove the conflicting location from path. That may help you